# MongoDB replica-set voting

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I have a three-member replica-set: one arbiter, one primary and one secondary. If the primary and the arbiter are both down, the only remaining secondary does not vote itself and/or not become primary.

Is this a limitation of MongoDB clustering? Can I force the only remaining secondary to vote itself as primary?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automated way to pick a primary when the majority of the set is down, you just do this manually.

This isn't really a limitation but more of keeping consistent replication, if half of the set is down it is considered that there is not enough voting members to come to a conclusion on what member should be primary. You can read more about the voting "method" it uses here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum

The MongoDB documentation states two methods you can use: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/